# JPA not mached query throwing null pointer exception using hibernat in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I using get hibernate to get data. When i called data using specific parameter which return not query result, it shows bellow error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.rms.service.impl.ProductsServiceImpl.getAppProductItems(ProductsServiceImpl.java:143)
    at com.rms.controller.RmsMobileAppController.getAppProductItems(RmsMobileAppController.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62).......
```

Here is my entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RmsOptions")
public class RmsOptionsEntity implements Serializable { 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;    
    private String hardCode;
    private String softCode;
    private String codeDes;
    private String status;
    // getter setter
}
```

Here is my repository

```
public interface RmsOptionsRepo extends JpaRepository<RmsOptionsEntity, Long>{
    
      @Query(" FROM RmsOptionsEntity WHERE hardCode = ?1 AND softCode =?2 AND status = 1")
      RmsOptionsEntity getcodeDes(String hardCode,String softcord);
    
    }
```

I called from **ProductsServiceImpl** class which is my service class . if parameter values matched it is working fine. When parameter values found no match it shows the error...
**Here is my service**

```
    @Service
public class ProductsServiceImpl implements ProductsService {   
  @Autowired
private ProductCategoriesRepo productCategoriesRepo;

    @Autowired
    private RmsOptionsRepo rmsOptionsRepo;
    
    @Override
    public List<ProductAppItemsModel> getAppProductItems(String restaurantId, String restaurantBranchId) {

        List<ProductAppItemsModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
        List<ProductCategoriesInfo> productCatgoriesList = productCategoriesRepo.getProductCatgoriesList(restaurantId, restaurantBranchId);
        try {
        
        for (ProductCategoriesInfo categoriesInfo:productCatgoriesList){            
            List<ProductsInfo> products = productsRepo.getProducts(restaurantId, restaurantBranchId, categoriesInfo.getProductCategoryId());

         } 
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }

}
```

How to handle null pointer exception. I just used now try...catch. Please suggest me..

Comment: Which line is line 143?  Some object is NULL.  Test for it.  If if it a bug fix it.  Just catching the Exception is wrong.

Comment: @ScaryWombat RmsOptionsEntity rmsOption = rmsOptionsRepo.getcodeDes("CUR", stock.getCurrencyCode()); is the 143 line

Comment: it is in ProductsServiceImpl  class ... which line called to repository.

Comment: I think, you are missing this repository injection in your service class `productCategoriesRepo` ? Also, don't see where `productsRepo` is coming as well, is the service class above complete?

Comment: @code_mechanic I have injected in my project code... here i remove..now i added to my code..

Comment: Line 143, you mentioned in previous comments, may have null pointer at two places, either your `rmsOptions` is null or the `stock` variable is null, can you check that?

Comment: @code_mechanic thanks I made a big mistake stock is null...

Comment: That code is not even in your question.

Answer (score 2):

if you use  `jpaRepo` its a better way to create a method

public interface RmsOptionsRepo extends JpaRepository<RmsOptionsEntity, Long>{

```
      @Query("SELECT * FROM RmsOptionsEntity WHERE hardCode = ?1 AND softCode =?2 AND status = 1")
      RmsOptionsEntity findCodeDes(String hardCode,String softcord);
    
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't there be a SELECT in the start of the query?

```
public interface RmsOptionsRepo extends JpaRepository<RmsOptionsEntity, Long>{
    
      @Query("SELECT * FROM RmsOptionsEntity WHERE hardCode = ?1 AND softCode =?2 AND status = 1")
  RmsOptionsEntity getcodeDes(String hardCode,String softcord);    
}
```